What is the origin of the term POVM?
In Nielsen Chuang section 2.2.6 as they are introducing POVMs they write “The acronym POVM stands for ‘Positive Operator-Valued Measure’, a technical term whose historical origins we won’t worry about.” I was curious and tried to google the origin of the term and got absolutely nothing. Understanding the origins of terms tends to help me keep them all straight. Does anyone know where the term came from?

Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/what-is-a-povm

It is a measure whose values are positive semidefinite operators, as opposed to the usual case of non-negative real numbers. Wikipedia talks a bit about it from the measure point of view.
